# OpenFileDialog Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, openfiledialog

I have no problems with using of OpenFileDialog (in Windows Forms).
I can not understand for sure where the error using OpenFileDialog in Silverlight( WPF). In my code I am interested by this string , where it necessary to show the path:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(fileStream);
```

**all code for Silverlight (does not work):**

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog opendialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        System.IO.Stream fileStream = opendialog.File.OpenRead();
        if (opendialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadLines(fileStream); 
            string pattern = @"set vrouter ""([\w-]+)""";

            var matches =
                lines.SelectMany(line => Regex.Matches(line, pattern)
                    .Cast<Match>()).Where(m => m.Success)
                    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                    .Distinct();

            foreach (String match in matches)
            {

                textBox1.AppendText(match + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Code for Windows Forms (works well):**

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog opendialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (opendialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadLines(opendialog.FileName);
            string pattern = @"set vrouter ""([\w-]+)""";

                var matches = 
                    lines.SelectMany(line=> Regex.Matches(line, pattern)
                        .Cast<Match>()).Where(m => m.Success)
                        .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                        .Distinct();

                foreach (String match in matches)
                {

                        textBox1.AppendText(match + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight runs with **elevated** permissions by default(simply saying in sandbox), it means

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(fileStream);
```

wil not work, for 2 reasons:

1. parameter should be string path, not a stream in silverlight api, at least.
2. File.ReadLines will not work, because it works only for trusted applications.

based on above, your issue can be solved by following code:

```
OpenFileDialog opendialog = new OpenFileDialog();
if (opendialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
   string text = string.Empty;
   using (StreamReader reader = opendialog.File.OpenText()) 
   {
   text = reader.ReadToEnd();
   }
   // do stuff here
}
```

or another options provided by msdn : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221415(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: here the error is gone, but it appeared in string-code  lines.SelectMany(line => Regex.Matches(line, pattern)/. Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(string, string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: don't know what you're trying to reach. but the idea is simple. parse a string, filled by StreamReader.

Comment: I added code for Windows Forms/ It works excellent. But I need the same code in Silverlight.there is a problem

Comment: once again, windows forms and silverlight are different things. first  runs on desktop(full trust),  second in browser(possible on desktop, there is a appropriate feature) with elevated rights.  Of course it's based on the goal you need to reach, but overall, you will have to deal with Silverlight, i.e. write other code to get your stuff up and running.

Comment: your logic is clear to me and it is true! but my imagination and knowledge is not enough! but I will try! Thanks for your participation!

Comment: no problems. hope you'will resolve your issues soon :).

Answer (score 0):

found that I was searching for! this example (with OpenFileDialog Silverlight) works well:

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog opendialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        opendialog.Multiselect = true;
        bool? dialogResult = opendialog.ShowDialog();
        if (dialogResult.HasValue && dialogResult.Value)
        {
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
            foreach (var file in opendialog.Files)
            {
                Stream fileStream = file.OpenRead();
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                {

                    string pattern = @"set vrouter ""([\w-]+)""";
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        var matches =
                            Regex.Matches(reader.ReadToEnd(), pattern)
                                .Cast<Match>().Where(m => m.Success)
                                .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                                .Distinct();

                        foreach (var match in matches)
                        {

                            textBox1.Text += val;
                        }
```